# Why we use setPropertyActionListener in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working with JSF and Primefaces. I used setPropertyActionListener from a JSF demo example. It is working, but I don't understand the specific purpose of it.

```
<p:commandButton value="Search" ajax="false" 
  action="#{scmAirLiftApprovalRequestManager.search}">
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" 
     target="#{scmAirLiftApprovalRequestManager.isSearching}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Can anyone explain in simple what actually it doing?

Comment: It's one of several ways to pass _parameters_ from the view to the backing bean.

Comment: Depending on the context variable, sometimes is much more convenient to use a method param, available in EL 2.2, to just pass it as `#{scmAirLiftApprovalRequestManager.search(true)}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<f:setPropertyActionListener>` sets directly a property in the managed bean.

In the provided snippet of yours, the `#{scmAirLiftApprovalRequestManager.isSearching}` property will be set to `true` when the `<p:commandButton>`'s action is invoked.

More info:

- [JSF's setPropertyActionListener attribute](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_setpropertyactionlistener_tag.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It is used to set a value directly into the property of your backing bean before calling the action.

So, here only after setting the value `true` to `scmAirLiftApprovalRequestManager.isSearching` , a method `scmAirLiftApprovalRequestManager.search` is called.